# Implementing Search Efficiently in ListView UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I have an AutoSuggestBox and in the textchanged event I set the itemsSource of the Listview each time the text is changed.

```
        var box = sender as AutoSuggestBox;
        var searchString = box.Text;
        labelFolder.ItemsSource = AllTags.Where(p => p.NAME.Contains(searchString));
```

Is this good practice? If not, Is there any efficient way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `AllTags` will contains thousands of elements - I suppose it will be inefficient. In addition, probably, `TextChanged` event launches after every tap on the keyboard and data reloading is very frequent which could slow your app. 
It is a good idea to take a look at the Reactive Extensions in such cases. With Rx you can easily delay data refreshing when user type very fast and select eg. first 20 elements of the `Where` result.

```
var searchObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern(s => box.TextChanged +=  s, s => box.TextChanged -= s)
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400))
.Select(result =>
    {
        var textBox = result.Sender as AutoSuggestBox;
        return textBox.Text;
    }
);

searchObservable
.DistinctUntilChanged()
.ObserveOnDispatcher()
.Subscribe(searchString =>
    {
          //Select elements from 'AllTags' here, this code will be launched with 400ms delay (throttle) when user is typing fast.
    }
```

Note, this example is very general, but you can base on it.

At first glance, Rx looks difficult, but there are a lot of [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873541/search-on-textchanged-with-reactive-extensions) and [tutorials](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html) about it.